# Computing Follow sets of Grammar for LL(1) parser

Tags: compilers, parsers, sets

I am trying to compute the **Follow** set of the following Grammar:

```
E -> E' E A
A -> + | *
E -> num
E' -> num
```

I start by adding the end of string symbol, via. some non-terminal **S** such that:

```
S -> E$
E -> E' E A
A -> + | *
E -> num
E' -> num
```

Becomes the Grammar. With this I get the following set constraints for the productions:

```
Production             Set Constraint
S -> E$                {$} <= Follow(E)
E -> E' E A            First(A) <= Follow(E)
A -> + | *             {+,*} <= Follow(A)
E -> num               {num} <= Follow(E)
E' -> num              {num} <= Follow(E')
```

With the above constraints, I can solve these with the following result:

```
set           initial      Iteration 1          ...
Follow(E)     {$, num}     {$, num, +, *}       ...
Follow(A)     {+,*}        {+,*}                ...
Folloe(E')    {num}        {num}                ...
```

With further iterations no changes are made to the **Follow** sets and thus the final result I get is:

```
Follow(E)  = {$, num, +, *}
Follow(A)  = {+,*}
Follow(E') = num
```

However, can anyone verify if what I have done above is correct? I just recently learned how to compute these sets - and I am exercising with LL(1) parser construction.

Comment: Also Follow(A) contains Follow(E)
checkout this page https://www.jambe.co.nz/UNI/FirstAndFollowSets.html

Comment: @MarkRegev How come? I tried to check out the webside you provided a link to, but from what I can see, there should never be a case where an `A` can be followed by a `E`?

Comment: Rule 3. Also how did num get into the follow set of E?
The solution should be
Follow(E)  = {$, +, *}
Follow(A)  = {$, +, *}
Follow(E') = {num}

Comment: @MarkRegev Yeah I make sense of it now. The webside however, can be a bit confusing as some of the rules only applies if __nullable__ of a predicate is true, which is clearly stated in the rules that are mentioned. Thanks for clarifying though :-)